# PayPal and transfer to multiple bank accounts

Tags: node.js, rest, paypal

I'm currently developing an app where user A can buy something from user B.

What I want to do is let user A make a payment with PayPal. Then on backend I increase account balance of user B in my database and then allow user B to withdraw this money to his bank account. And here is my question, is it possible to transfer money from PayPal to various bank accounts? Eg user B sends his bank account number through a form and on backend I make proper API call to transfer money.

If not with PayPal then how can I perform this type of transfer, possibly with other service?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does not transfer money directly to users' bank accounts, but rather between PayPal accounts.

User A could pay User B's PayPal account, via a PayPal Checkout https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client set up with User B's email address in the purchase_unit's ['payee' object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/)

---

(User B could later withdraw this money from their PayPal account to their bank or do whatever else with it; that's up to them)

Comment: Thank you I get it. Can I even perform this kind of transactions (like I described above, from some PayPal like service to someone's bank account)?